# Zend_Currency Displaying Extra Character

Tags: zend-framework

I was trying to use Zend_Currency to format my currency outputs and i face this queer problem. An illegal character(Â) gets displayed along with the output of the currency data. The code i used is:

```
  $currency = new Zend_Currency('en_IN');
  echo $currency->toCurrency(100);
```

And the output is:

```
 RsÂ 100.00
```

I dont know from where the "Â" comes up. I found out that this problem occurs for certain locales only. It is working fine for en_US and some others but output this extra char Â in many other. Some one please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your layout header, this is an regular encoding issue.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Elzo's answer, I have this in my Bootstrap.php:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
$view->headMeta()->setHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This is in my layout:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
</head>
```